# BroadcastReceiver for CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE, WIFI_STATE_CHANGED and PROVIDER_CHANGED

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-broadcast

I have a `MyBroadcastReceiver` setup like so:

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

As you can see it "listens" for `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`, `WIFI_STATE_CHANGED` and `PROVIDER_CHANGED`.

The first two are working great, and my `BroadcastReceiver` gets called.
However, it never gets called upon `PROVIDER_CHANGED` (when I disable location on my Android 5.1).

`MyBroadcastReceiver` is roughly this at the moment:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.d("ACTION", action);
    // ...
}
```

I tried different `AndroidManifest.xml` configurations but never gets the `PROVIDER_CHANGED` broadcast.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you set  `<data android:scheme="content"/>
        <data android:host="com.android.THEHOST"/>` in the corresponding intent-filter does it help?

Comment: @SatelliteSD what host should I put then for `PROVIDER_CHANGED`?

Comment: @SatelliteSD adding `<data android:scheme="content"/>` did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, auto-completion made me use a wrong `IntentFilter` action.

```
 <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
```

Should be used, not `android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED` of course.

Comment: Yes, it works when the app is around, have you tried it when app is killed/closed? Coz, in my case it doesn,t work when app is killed/closed.